# Unanswered old question

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Two days ago I asked a question on "Ask Different" (one of Stack Exchange's asking websites) and I had no answers.
I think no experts saw my question.

Today I'm trying to send the same question again to "Ask Different", maybe some experts are online now. But the Stack Exchange application told me that a similar question has been already asked. Even after changing few words, I can't ask that question again.

So I want to know if there's a way to ask that question again OR to make it appear on top of the list of newly asked questions?

Comment: If you have legitimate edits including things like spelling, grammar, formatting, or something that will make the question more legible, I think that's an honest and fair way to bump your question. For instance, [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223631/) has a spelling error in the title, and some missing punctuation. As an editor, I might come along and adjust those, but only if the question seems like a good fit for the site. You can do that yourself. In fact, it helps future readers. Please don't think I'm criticizing the way you wrote your question, just offering an option!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things you can do, but re-posting isn't one of them. We want the answers to questions in one place, and don't want people to keep asking the same question.

If you have 75 or more points, you can put a bounty on your question to give it more views.
If you have a Stack Exchange account anywhere with 200 or more points, you can associate that account with your account on Ask Different; this gives you a 100 point association bonus on Ask Different.

Alternatively, you can use some of your own social media to attract attention to the question.

If new information has become available, then you can edit it with the new information. This bumps the question. But, *don't* do this just to bump your question, that is considered abuse of the system. Use it to add additional information.
Note that "I found [...] on the internet, but this didn't help in my situation" is a valid addition to your question. Explain in your edit why that didn't help, what results you got when you tried it. So, after posting on SE, actively keep looking for answers. (And if you find the answer elsewhere, please *do* post it as an answer on your own question too - it might help future visitors).